# SQL Server - Remove/Delete Specific part of the records of a table

Tags: sql-server

I have an SQL Server 2012 with 2.047 records in a table that I call `dbo.tblTest`.
All the records rely on the following formula,

```
SomeTextX.pdd_openslam_SomeTextY
```

Now what I want to do is to remove the **`_openSlam_SomeTextY`**
and all the records become **`SomeTextX.pdd`**

All Best,
Konstantinos

Comment: Um, what?  I'm not sure I understand your question.  Sample data and desired results are always helpful...

Comment: Sorry I guess i used some symbols that editor did not allow to show and the question was not easy to understand. Can you check now please?

Comment: Not understanding your question

Comment: Hi - lets say we have 2 records -> A) rec1.jpg.sometext B) rec2.jpg.someOtherText // Is there anyway to remove the part after .jpg so the records would be A) rec1.jpg B) rec2.jpg  Thanks

Comment: Is that part you want to remove from the file extension always the same?

Comment: No thats my problem its not! The only part that is always the same is the .pdd part in the middle of the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you can use `charindex` with `left`:

```
select left(yourfield, charindex('pdd_', yourfield) + 2)
from yourtable
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b7687/1)

If you actually want to `update` the data instead, this will work:

```
update yourtable
set yourfield = left(yourfield, charindex('pdd_', yourfield) + 2)
```

- [More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/21fc6/1)

Comment: I am giving a try and let you know! Thanks!